# Moving Legacy .php url extensions to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, php-extension

Is it possible to add a .php extension to laravel routes like so:

```
example.com/mypage.php
```

I am transitioning an old website into Laravel but don't want to change the URL for SEO purposes.

I notice there is a similar question that works for .html files in the routing web.php. i.e.

```
Route::get('mypage.html', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Which works fine but:

```
Route::get('mypage.php', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

returns - No input file specified.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: This looks like bad configuration of your webserver. Usually the webserver will delegate the processing of anything with the .php extension to a php handler (typically FPM nowadays) however if not configured correctly it will not check for the existance of the file first. Try checking your fastCGI configuration or your mod_php configuration (or the equivalent for your webserver)

Comment: example.com/index.php works fine. Though an index.php file actually exists.

Comment: That's because that file actually exists (I'm assuming)

Comment: how would I go about that using a mac and homestead Laravel set up?

Comment: Which webserver are you using and can you share your mod_php or php-fpm configuration (if you're not using the PHP development server)

Comment: VMbox, Homestead, Vagrant. php-fpm active  in phpinfo(). I'm not sure how to find the mod_php or php-fpm configuration in this set-up.

Comment: If it's running over apache it should be under `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpX.Y-fpm` usually the handler is set within a `FileMatch` block which requires a file to be matched. Might be worth a look

Comment: conf-enabled folder doesn't exist. I think this is a different set-up to mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as

```
Route::get('mypage.php', function () {
    echo 'Hello World';
});
```

or if you want to return view then use like that

```
Route::get('welcome.php', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Here welcome is your blade file name